# UISegmentedControl - Last Segment does not select easily

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

So I am using a UISegmented Control as shown[image]

The last segment the "5" is incredibly hard to hit with my finger. I noticed from the simulator using a cursor that about only half of the segment will respond. Anything to the right of the half is basically a deadzone. I am not sure what's causing this as I have moved this segmented control to the top and it still does the same thing. However, if I moved the segmented control to center of the screen, the 5 Segment entire surface area responds to touch events...

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Almost for certain there is some other view, transparent, but overlapping the segmented control.

Comment: @DavidH you were right. it is something on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what might be overlapping your code, add this UIVIew Category:

```
@interface UIView (Dumper_Private)

+ (void)appendView:(UIView *)v toStr:(NSMutableString *)str;

@end

@implementation UIView (Dumper_Private)

+ (void)appendView:(UIView *)a toStr:(NSMutableString *)str
{
    [str appendFormat:@"  %@: frame=%@ bounds=%@ layerFrame=%@ tag=%d userInteraction=%d alpha=%f hidden=%d\n", 
        NSStringFromClass([a class]),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.frame),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.bounds),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.layer.frame),
        a.tag, 
        a.userInteractionEnabled,
        a.alpha,
        a.isHidden
        ];
}

@end

@implementation UIView (Dumper)

+ (void)dumpSuperviews:(UIView *)v msg:(NSString *)msg
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];

    while(v) {
        [self appendView:v toStr:str];
        v = v.superview;
    }
    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    NSLog(@"%@:\n%@", msg, str);
}

+ (void)dumpSubviews:(UIView *)v msg:(NSString *)msg
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];

    if(v) [self appendView:v toStr:str];
    for(UIView *a in v.subviews) {
        [self appendView:a toStr:str];
    }
    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    NSLog(@"%@:\n%@", msg, str);
}

@end
```

and call `[UIView dumpSuperviews:theSegmentedControl];`

Comment: Yes, I tested all the views that were on top it seems it's a TableView that is causing this problem. The `UITableView` is covering 90% of the screen and the full width of the window. I'm not sure why it's causing only the right sliver of the screen to be unresponsive especially since the TableView is hidden.

Comment: So does hidden views really interfere with touch actions? I ended up going back into the code and manipulating the views using `bringSubviewToFront" and it seems to have resolved the issue. I am not sure if this is the best way to handle this. Do you have any ideas?